# PHP: Catching location to append id at nav menu

Tags: php, strpos, php-5.4

I'm using this PHP function to append `id="current"` to my nav menu according to the page you're in.

```
function get_current() {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $arg) !== false) {
            echo 'id="current"';
        }
    }
}
```

Simple HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li <?php get_current('') ?>><a>HOME</a></li>
    <li <?php get_current('page1.php') ?>><a>PAGE 1</a></li>
    <li <?php get_current('page2.php') ?>><a>PAGE 2</a></li>
    <li <?php get_current('page3.php') ?>><a>PAGE 3</a></li>
    <li <?php get_current('page4.php') ?>><a>PAGE 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

It works fine, except for the Home page. What argument should I use? The home page is at the root of the domain. I'd like to avoid forcing users to go to index.php and instead, set that as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would solve it like this:

```
<?
function get_current( $nav_page ) {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return ( $uri == $nav_page ) ? ' id="current" ' : '';
}
?>
```

And small changes in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li <?= get_current('/') ?> ><a>HOME</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page1.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 1</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page2.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 2</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page3.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 3</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page4.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please note that I changed the parameters to absolute URLs because `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains absolute path.

### EDIT:

Since you used `func_get_args()`, you might be going to accept arbitrary number of 'page-name.php' as parameter for `get_current()`. In that case, the `get_current` function becomes:

```
function get_current() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( in_array( $uri, func_get_args() ) )
        return ' id="current" ';
    return '';
}
```

and its accompanying HTML:

```
<li <?= get_current('/', '/index.php')?> > ... </li>
```

### EDIT2:

Your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` shows that files are in the `/new/` folder. Changed the logic to compare end-parts.

```
<?
function get_current( $nav_page ) {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return is_rear_match( $uri, $nav_page ) ? ' id="current" ' : '';
}

function is_rear_math( $haystack, $needle ) {
    $rear = substr($haystack, -strlen($needle));
    return $rear !== false && $rear === $needle;        
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li <?= get_current('/') ?> ><a>HOME</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page1.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 1</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page2.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 2</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page3.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 3</a></li>
    <li <?= get_current('/page4.php') ?> ><a>PAGE 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! :-)
I tried your first solution (http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/8915/qzw0.jpg) but id="current" isn't appended to any link anymore.. even the page-x.php.

Comment: typo: (...) even FOR the page(s)-x.php

Comment: I locally tested the code above (first solution) and it worked as expected. Please check the value of ``$uri`` immediately after ``$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];``, using ``var_dump($uri);``.

Comment: With var_dump I get this:

`<ul>`
 `<li string(16) "/page-1.php" ><a>HOME</a></li>`
 `<li string(16) "/page-1.php"><a>PAGE 1</a></li>`
 `<li string(16) "/page-1.php"><a>PAGE 2</a></li>`
 `<li string(16) "/page-1.php"><a>PAGE 3</a></li>`
 `...`
`</ul>`

Comment: I suggested using ``var_dump($uri);`` only for testing ``$uri``'s value. You can add ``print_r($_SERVER);exit();`` at the beginning of your file, and examine what's inside the ``$_SERVER`` variable, especially ``REQUEST_URI``.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38622/discussion-between-kita-and-multiformeingegno)

Comment: Ok, I'll be at home in 20 min :-)